# iOS call Web service don't get any data back

Tags: ios, web-services, wsdl2objc

I want to create an iOS-App, which calls a Web service (from SAP company). I followed these steps [here](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/803ae155-d81b-2e10-5c99-86f57900b083?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&50457276034896).

My problem is, I don't get any data back. I can give input parameter but I don't get any data back (Response). I get the WSDL body back without output parameters.

Can you help me please ?

```
2015-08-28 07:57:11.281 integerprobe[1094:34249] ResponseBody:
..xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style"....
```

Comment: This question makes me weep...

Comment: can you help me please??